# How Can I solve this error code in Xcode5.0.2? Thread 1 signal:SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, memory

I recently upgraded an app I created iOS 7. I then tried to run the app, and the build said it succeeded, however the app crashed and directed me to this code and the error message:

```
2014-03-03 14:40:24.686 BluetusRece[2112:a0b] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
'[<UIApplication 0xa06ad00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label_1.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x01bdc5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014ef8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01c6c6a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
3   Foundation                          0x000f49ee -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
4   Foundation                          0x00060cfb _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
5   Foundation                          0x00060253 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
6   Foundation                          0x000c270a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
7   UIKit                               0x00717a15 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015017d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
9   CoreFoundation                      0x01bd7b6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
10  UIKit                               0x0071656e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
11  UIKit                               0x007182fb -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 165
12  UIKit                               0x004753bb -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 58
13  UIKit                               0x004756e9 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 245
14  UIKit                               0x0047428f -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 543
15  UIKit                               0x0048887c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
16  UIKit                               0x00488de9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
17  UIKit                               0x00476025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
18  GraphicsServices                    0x02a242f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
19  GraphicsServices                    0x02a23e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
20  CoreFoundation                      0x01b57d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
21  CoreFoundation                      0x01b57a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
22  CoreFoundation                      0x01b8277c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
23  CoreFoundation                      0x01b81ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
24  CoreFoundation                      0x01b818db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
25  UIKit                               0x00473add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
26  UIKit                               0x00475d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
27  BluetusRece                         0x00003802 main + 130
28  libdyld.dylib                       0x02712725 start + 0
)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
 (lldb)
```

Comment: This looks like a dead outlet connection to a Label named `label_1`. See line one.

Comment: may be this is an issue with your xib. may be you forget to set reference or something else.

Answer (score 0):

This error caught from if you had already connected Interface Builder object is removed/renamed in its owner source

check out this link

[What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your startup view controller does not have an `IBOutlet` property named `label_1` that some `UILabel` is trying to connect to from your NIB or Storyboard file.

Please open your NIB or Storyboard and look for `UILabel` connected to `label_1` `IBOutlet` property in your startup view controller and then either delete the connection or add a property as below to your initial view controller's header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label_1;
```

This line is going to add missing `IBOutlet` and let you get past this crash.